# System.Windows.Application.get_MainWinndow() exception Windows Phone

Tags: exception, windows-phone-8

I have created a small app for Windows Phone 8. When I run it I get the following error:

> ((System.Windows.Application)(this)).MainWinndow threw an exception of type System.NotSupportedException at System.Windows.Application.get_MainWinndow()

I have searched for a solution to this but not much information out there.

My main page is called WelcomePage.xaml which is the first page that gets loaded and when exception is thrown during test on emmulator, but I'm not sure if that is the problem or even how to check if it is. My thinking being that I changed the name of MainPage.xaml to WelcomePage.xaml and this has maybe upset something.

Any ideas how I would go about solving the above problem, apologies I'm new to VS and Windows Phone C#?

J

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked ***WMAppManifest.xml*** file in `Properties` path?

In the **Application UI** Tab, the Navigation Page should be changed to **WelcomePage.xaml** but not `MainPage.xaml`.

Comment: yes just checked WMAppManifest.xml and WelcomePage.xaml is listed as Navigation Page!

Comment: MainWinndow is existed in your project?

Comment: no searched entire solution! _message Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications.

Comment: It looks like a WPF issue. And MainWinndow spell error. Can you add a new project to test.